# Obtaining English artwork for movies from the movie database

Tags: c#

I am trying to download the movie posters for a list of movies from the movie database https://www.themoviedb.org/. For some movies the artwork that is downloaded is not the English version. How do I make sure that each artwork that is downloaded is in English?

I am using TMDbLib.

My code currently is as follows:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
SearchContainer<SearchMovie> results = client.SearchMovie("Guardians of the Galaxy");
string year = "2014";

TMDbConfig cfg = new TMDbConfig();
Movie movie = new Movie();
string uri = "";
foreach (SearchMovie result in results.Results)
{
     movie = client.GetMovie(result.Id, MovieMethods.Credits | MovieMethods.Keywords | MovieMethods.Images | MovieMethods.Videos | MovieMethods.Reviews | MovieMethods.Releases);
     DateTime value = Convert.ToDateTime(movie.ReleaseDate);

     uri = GetMediaInformation.FetchImage(result.Id).ToString();
     Console.WriteLine(uri);
     if (year == value.Year.ToString())
         break;
 }
 byte[] bytes = webClient.DownloadData(uri);
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes);
 Image artWork = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

Which returns the following image:
[image]

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: I'm using TMDbLib

Comment: Then I'd suggest raising it with the package maintainers. According to the TMDb API docs they give the poster matching the language you specify, or an English one, or the highest rated one.

Comment: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/getting-started/btRcZmKXu25GbQ5Sv look at the language section in the official documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to set the default language to English, like so:

```
client.DefaultLanguage = "en";
```

Note that this is case sensitive, according to [this issue](https://github.com/LordMike/TMDbLib/issues/200)